How do you use the IF Function to format the removal of leading 0's?
The below code returned an error: "Argument '3' in FORMAT is required."
FormattedDuration =
IF(
    ISBLANK(DurationColumn),
    BLANK(),
    VAR Days = INT(DurationColumn)
    VAR Hours = INT((DurationColumn - Days) * 24)
    VAR Minutes = INT(MOD((DurationColumn - Days) * 24 * 60, 60))
    VAR Seconds = ROUND(MOD((DurationColumn - Days) * 24 * 60 * 60, 60), 0)
    VAR DayFormat =
        IF(Days < 10, FORMAT(Days, "0#"), FORMAT(Days, "00"))
    RETURN
        DayFormat & " days, " &
        FORMAT(Hours, "00") & ":" &
        FORMAT(Minutes, "00") & ":" &
        FORMAT(Seconds, "00")
)

Having formatted the days in my duration column to "000", i wanted to add an IF clause to remove a '0', if no. of days = <100 and again if <10. So if 25 days it would appear as '25days' and not '025days' etc. I attempted it for <10 1st:

VAR DayFormat =
IF(Days <10, FORMAT(Days, "0#",), FORMAT (Days, "00",))
but without success.
This addition returned the error:Argument '3' in Format Function is required, not the desired result.

